# Optimize search-as-you-type performance on a ExtJS treeview

Tags: performance, optimization, extjs, extjs4, treeview

I have an ExtJS treeview bound to a store which has large number (~1000) of nodes (having Checkbox attached with each of them to select them) and 3 levels of nesting to be precise.

And, I have a textbox just above the treeview widget in which user can type in the node and based on text entered, treeview will show/hide relevant nodes for the criteria.

The business logic here is such that, for certain combination of selected nodes from the tree, only certain nodes should be shown (be it via search or directly).

Example.

```
Food
   |___ Vegetables
            |___ Potato, Tomato, Brinjal, Carrot
   |___ Fruits
            |___ Banana, Apple, Grapes, Watermelon

Electronics
   |___ Home Appliances
            |___ TV, Fridge, A.C., Washing Machine.
   |___ Personal
            |___ Mobile, Tablet, Laptop
```

Now, consider that, if user selected any item from `Fruits` category, then Items from `Electronics > Personal` category should **NOT** be visible in treeview, neither directly nor in search results. I know it doesn't make any sense but just to give you brief idea of how relations would work in treeview.

Now the problem is, logic to perform search, hiding/showing nodes based on selection is all present, but since amount of data is large (and the code is pretty old and we can't afford to rewrite everything from scratch at least for now), **search-as-you-type** tends to slow down occasionally. And it is drastically slow in IE8 lower.

On my testing, the performance is slow in general is because each key-stroke made into search box leads to whole tree-traversal and checking/manipulating the UI logic along with business logic whether to show or hide them.

And considering standard users' typing speed, input of each character becomes slower since lot of behind-the-scene computation is done for each `change` in search-box.

So, how can I speed up the things here (even if its in smaller amounts)?

For solution, I considered delaying search by, say 1500ms, after input, so that if user types fast, treeview can wait until he's done typing, and then takes the search key for searching. But, better and feasible suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It's hard to put micro-optimizations in code we can't see assuming that's what you want.

Comment: It really sounds like your best option would be to put a button next to the search field that invokes the search instead of on user typing.

Comment: @Reimius: That is actually my last option as I don't wanna loose instant searching. I could post the code but there's whole JS file for the treeview with some 1500+ LOC (blame old developers to created it) and logic for search is spread across multiple methods.

Comment: Well...  If you don't want your code changed...  and you don't want to change the functionality...  you're kind of asking a question that doesn't have an answer.

Comment: @Reimius: I'm asking question since I don't have an answer except for the option which I've already mentioned. May be I can traverse whole store only at time of saving the entire form, make search and hiding only for visual purpose, may be I search from only raw text of treeview rather than underlying store, I don't know what are options available to me, that's why I've asked the question.

Comment: Inlaid the problem with your question is that you are telling us what you are doing and not how you are doing it.  Your last comment mentions a form, and the question says nothing about that as an example, this herein shows that you are not telling us enough about how your current system works for us to even suggest improvement.  SO is for concrete questions and answers.  I'm not trying to be mean or anything, it's just that you are offering almost nothing to work from to provide an answer.

Comment: @Reimius: Apologies, I'll update the question once I get home, may be even set bounty as its critical for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: On a side note, if you want to implement the delay you suggest in your question, how do you plan on doing it?  It seems to me, if done correctly is probably a good solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28383/discussion-between-kush-and-reimius)